# I can't connect to https://localhost:44300 without Fiddler running

Tags: fiddler

So I cannot connect to my IISExpress website on https without Fiddler running now.

I have tried:

1. Disabling "Capture HTTPS CONNECTs" in Fiddler Options.
2. Ensuring that my Windows proxy setting is set to "Off".
3. Ensuring that the "Use a proxy ..." LAN Settings via IE are unchecked.
4. I deleted all of the Fiddler certs from my local cert store.
5. I tried uninstalling Fiddler.

Anyone got any ideas of what I haven't tried?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in google chrome. This fixed it for me: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost